# How to get values from list in variables in dart

Tags: dart, iterable-unpacking

I have seen the following in Python:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
first_number, *other_numbers, last_number = my_list

# here first_number becomes 1, other_numbers becomes [2, 3] and last_number becomes 4
```

how to use that `*` in dart with the same values.

I tried:

```dart
void main () {
  List<int> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  var first_number, *other_numbers, last_number = my_list;
}
```

but the above is a syntax error

Comment: Pattern matching for assignment has been proposed, but is not yet implemented or released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach the problem will be to use [List.getRange()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/getRange.html);

Your code will become something like:

```dart
void main () {
  List<int> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  var first_number = my_list[0], other_numbers = my_list.getRange(1,3), last_number = my_list[3]; 
  print(first_number);
  print(other_numbers);
  print(last_number);
}
```